# Flex Popup not setting child CSS from global style sheet

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, popup

I have a CustomListItemRenderer class. It's styling, and contained components' styling, are set via an external CSS stylesheet.

When this renderer is used in a list in the main application, everything is set and styled correctly. When this renderer is being used in a list inside of a popup opened through the PopupManager class, the styling is not being set correctly.

This is a Flex Web Application: SDK 4.1

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define it in your CSS also as something like PopupManager CustomListItemRenderer{} since popups use different style ancestors. So defining it specifically for use in popups again will fix your issue.